# What to include in gitignore for a Laravel and PHPStorm project?

Tags: php, git, laravel, phpstorm

I'm going to be collaborating on a project using Laravel and PHPStorm. After doing some research and working on a few projects, here is the `.gitignore` I've come up with so far.

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
/vendor
/node_modules
composer.phar
composer.lock
.env.*.php
.env.php
.DS_Store
workspace.xml
Thumbs.db
```

Are there any other files that I might be overlooking that could cause conflicts?

EDIT:

For anyone wondering why Flosculus comment is there, I originally posted that I was having issues with the .idea/workspace file showing up in my git history, and his answer is how to remove it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The title asks for what to include, you ask about a problem you're having with `gitignore`, and then you ask if you've overlooked anything. The meat of your problem sounds like a problem with your `gitignore` file yet you focus on Laravel instead

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I guess I'm just looking for feedback on whether or not this .gitignore needs anything else added to it.

Comment: You don't want to exclude composer.lock -- see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#commit-your-composer-lock-file-to-version-control -- and I personally like to commit my vendor/ subdirectory as I tend to end up having to patch or alter many packages, and don't always have time to create new repos ... probably a bad habit.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unless PHPStorm is an official part of the project (e.g. it's mandated by a company, or agreed to by all team members) I would urge you to put its ignore settings into `.git/info/exclude` instead of `.gitignore`. The former is local to your copy, the latter should be committed and shared.

[gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) suggests [this for Laravel](https://www.gitignore.io/api/laravel):

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/laravel

### Laravel ###
vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json

# Rocketeer PHP task runner and deployment package. https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer
.rocketeer/
```

and [this for PHPStorm](https://www.gitignore.io/api/phpstorm):

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/phpstorm

### PhpStorm ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and Webstorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff:
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.xml
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

### PhpStorm Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml
# .idea/misc.xml
# *.ipr
```

As an aside, gitignore.io can be [accessed via the command-line](https://docs.gitignore.io/install/command-line), so you can do things like

```
gi laravel,phpstorm >> .gitignore
```

It's a pretty handy little tool.

Comment: I found conflicting information on this: why not add public/js and public/css to the .gitignore here, too?

Comment: Why would you want to ignore those directories? In any case, I'm just showing what gitignore.io (now owned by Toptal) recommends. The same content can be found in [the `github/gitignore` repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Laravel.gitignore).

Answer (score 4):

Laravel automatically create it after installation:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
```

Comment: This was true of older projects. I just created several today and they no longer add this.

Answer (score 3):

I use this smart .gitignore file ;) , Hope it may help someone:

```
/node_modules
# ignore log files and databases
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite
# ignore compiled files
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so
# ignore packaged files
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip
# ignore OS generated files
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
# ignore Editor files
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
*.komodoproject
_ide_helper.php
/.idea
/.vscode
# Eclipse project files
.buildpath
.project
.settings/
# Ignore cache
.cache/
# Ignore user created files :)
*.bak
*.orig
# Ignore system files
.bash_history
LICENSE_AFL.txt
LICENSE.html
LICENSE.txt
LICENSE_EE*
RELEASE_NOTES.txt
.ssh/
error_log
.htpasswds
/.htaccess
php.ini.sample
.modgit/
_vti_bin/
_vti_cnf/
_vti_inf.html
_vti_log/
_vti_pvt/
_vti_txt/
tmp/
php.ini
_old/
.htpasswds/
.htpasswd
.viminfo
.profile
.bashrc
.bash_logout
.modman/
pkginfo
nohup.out
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
/.vagrant
.phpunit.result.cache
#Laravel Specific files
/vendor
.env
/public/.htaccess
/storage
storage/*.key
```

Answer (score -8):

```
rm -rf .idea
git-ignore .idea/
git commit -a -m 'deleted and ignored .idea/'
```

Reload project.

Comment: I would advise against deleting directories willy-nilly, instead keeping them but removing them tracking might be a better idea here.

In other words, add .idea/ to gitignore, but do something like:
`git rm -r --cached .idea/`

Comment: @MarlonvanderLinde Is right. You definitely don't want to straight up force recursive delete the .idea folder. If you've been working on the project a while you probably have some configurations in there and project-related settings that you don't want to lose. I've deleted it by accident before and it's a *huge* pain to get back. That's not to say don't gitignore it... but just don't remove it completely.

Comment: @MarlonvanderLinde Oh how years past catch up with you, I don't actually do this anymore :P

Comment: @flosculus Whether or not you do, they are still read by others, for years to come. :-)

Comment: Maybe you should delete this answer then?