# How do teams collaborate on a Laravel project using github?

Tags: laravel, git, github, phpstorm, gitignore

I'm currently in a team developing a LARAVEL project and all of us are using PHPSTORM, so we decide to use GitHub to make things easier.
so when I tried to push my project to GitHub then I remarked that not all files are included and that because of an existing .gitignore file in my LARAVEL project which is created by LARAVEL installer .. I searched for that and I fund the same case as I have: [What to include in gitignore for a Laravel and PHPStorm project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748132/what-to-include-in-gitignore-for-a-laravel-and-phpstorm-project)
but I didn't understand what we should ignore and why.
anyone can explain this in detail please I'm really a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description by [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) :

A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected; see the [NOTES](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) below for details.

useful links explain Laravel gitignore.

- [A good start for Laravel gitignore](https://medium.com/@technobollox/a-good-start-on-a-laravel-gitignore-file-6c4656aec2d)
- [Laravel what should be ignored.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/gitignore-what-should-be-ignored)